# C++ exposing member of private object

Tags: c++

In such an instance:

```
class A
{
private:
    B b;
};

class B
{
private:
    C c;
};

class C
{
public:
    void func();
};
```

Is there a way to make func() visible to A, or do I have to use an intermediate call in B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `c` is `private` in `B`, so instances of `A` cannot access it.

You will have to add an appropriate accessor to `B`.

This could forward the `func` call, like `void B::func() { return c.func(); }`.

Or, it could expose the `c` directly, like `C& B::getC() { return c; }` then `b.getC().func()`.

Only you can decide what `B` should "let" other classes do with its stuff.

Comment: You could declare A as a friend class of B.